# Firefox’s urlbar blacked out on new user

Tags: lubuntu, firefox

I created a new user account on my Lubuntu laptop today. When I opened Firefox and typed an address into the urlbar, this happened:

[image]

While the purpose of this new user is just to allow people to stay on more or less the same site, it is irritating to have a censored urlbar around.

It happened immediately after opening Firefox without any configurations the first time, the other user’s (= my) Firefox works like a charm.

Classic Theme Restorer or the `about:config` entry `browser.urlbar.formatting.enabled = false` didn’t work. Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: @Wilf, in the answer I've linked to a bug indicating that the reason may have more to do with hardware rather than the OS, per se.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"go to `about:config`, set `gfx.xrender.enabled` to `false`, restart the browser, and retry." from [comment #23 here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1005501#c23).

Apparently, the issue may not be limited to Lubuntu but be more of a hardware issue. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1314924.